# Powershell IIS Log Time-Taken Greater Than

Tags: powershell, iis-7, w3c

I'm trying to get an accurate count of requests with time-taken greater than 999 ms. I've tried using this script:

http://wingleungchan.blogspot.com/2011/04/parsing-iis-logs-with-powershell.html

but it doesn't accurately pick up numbers greater than 999. Is there an effective way of sorting an integer-based IIS(W3C) field in Powershell?

FYI: I'm running Windows 2008. Please don't suggest I use Log Parser. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried using any other scripts? A quick search shows there are a few available, such as: http://poshcode.org/2574. Once you find a script that seems to be parsing the desired values correctly, getting the results you want should be trivial.

Comment: Checking out that script, thanks!

Comment: I use the script @dugas provided a link to with some of my own modifications. Its an excellent place to start. Post back if you need help correlating the fields to compare. Please remember that this script assumes you're logging every field available in IIS.

Comment: I'm getting an assembly error while trying to process the script. I'm having to run "add-type -assemblyname system.web" before I run the script. Is there a way to add this into the script? Also, is there a way to speed up processing, perhaps selecting only the last 1000 lines?

Comment: Why is MS Log Parser not an option? In a past life where I had to do this sort of thing regularly, that was my go-to.

Comment: Another vote for `LogParser`. It's the right tool for this kind of job. No need to re-invent the wheel.

Answer (score 1):

## Import-Iis-Log

Since the helpful link (https://poshcode.org/2574) posted by the upvoted comment in the question is broken, below is the original content (PowerShell script) on the web page (in case it helps anyone):

### Import-Iis-Log by Mark Shevchenko

Read in an IIS `*log` file saved in format W3C.

The `Import-Iis-Log` cmdlet provides a way for you to read in data from an IIS `*log` file (saved in format W3C) and then display that data in tabular format within the Windows PowerShell console.

### Parameters:

- `Path` (string, required, position = 0, value from pipeline, not null, not empty) Specifies the path to the IIS *.log file to import. You can also pipe a path to Import-Iss-Log.
- `Delimiter` (string, position = 1, not null, not empty) Specified the delimiter that separated the property values in the IIS *log file. The default value is a spacebar.
- `Encoding` (Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.FileSystemCmdletProviderEncoding) The character encoding for the IIS *.log file. The default value is the UTF8.

### The cmdlet outputs in the pipeline objects with following properties:

`DateTime` (System.DateTime) Combined “date” and “time” values of a log.

`ClientHost` (System.Net.IpAddress) “c-ip” value of a log.

`UserName` (string or $null for anonymous user) “cs-username” value of a log.

`Service` (string) “s-sitename” value of a log.

`Machine` (string) “s-computername” value of a log.

`ServerIp` (System.Net.IpAddress) “s-ip” value of a log.

`ServerPort` (int) “s-port” value of a log.

`Method` (string) “cs-method” value of a log.

`ScriptPath` (string) “cs-uri-stem” value of a log, decoded with System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlDecode.

`QueryString` (string or $null for HTTP requests without query string) “cs-uri-query” value of a log, decoded with System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlDecode.

`ServiceStatus` (int) “sc-status” value of a log.

`ServiceSubStatus` (int) “sc-substatus” value of a log.

`Win32Status` (int) “sc-win32-status” value of a log.

`BytesSent` (System.UInt64) “sc-bytes” value of a log.

`BytesRecived` (System.UInt64) “cs-bytes” value of a log.

`ProcessingTime` (int) “time-taken” value of a log.

`ProtocolVersion` (string) “cs-version” value of a log.

`Host` (string of $null for HTTP requests without Host header) “cs-host” value of a log.

`UserAgent` (string or $null for request without an User-Agent header) “cs(User-Agent)” value of a log.

`Cookie` (string or $null for requests without a cookie) “cs(Cookie)” value of a log.

`Referer` (string or $null for requests without a referer) “cs(Referer)” value of a log, decoded with System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlDecode.

```
param
(
    [Parameter(
        Mandatory=$true,
        Position = 0,
        ValueFromPipeline=$true,
        HelpMessage="Specifies the path to the IIS *.log file to import. You can also pipe a path to Import-Iss-Log."
    )]
    [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
    [string]
    $Path,
    
    [Parameter(
        Position = 1,
        HelpMessage="Specifies the delimiter that separates the property values in the IIS *.log file. The default is a spacebar."
    )]
    [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
    [string]
    $Delimiter = " ",
    
    [Parameter(HelpMessage="The character encoding for the IIS *log file. The default is the UTF8.")]
    [Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.FileSystemCmdletProviderEncoding]
    $Encoding = [Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.FileSystemCmdletProviderEncoding]::UTF8
)
    
begin
{
    $fieldNames = @()
    
    $output = New-Object Object
    Add-Member -InputObject $output -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "DateTime" -Value $null
    Add-Member -InputObject $output -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "ClientHost" -Value $null
    Add-Member -InputObject $output -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "UserName" -Value $null
    Add-Member -InputObject $output -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Service" -Value $null
    Add-Member -InputObject $output -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Machine" -Value $null
    Add-Member -InputObject $output -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "ServerIp" -Value $null
    Add-Member -InputObject $output -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "ServerPort" -Value $null
    Add-Member -InputObject $output -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Method" -Value $null
    Add-Member -InputObject $output -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "ScriptPath" -Value $null
    Add-Member -InputObject $output -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "QueryString" -Value $null
    Add-Member -InputObject $output -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "ServiceStatus" -Value $null
    Add-Member -InputObject $output -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "ServiceSubStatus" -Value $null
    Add-Member -InputObject $output -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Win32Status" -Value $null
    Add-Member -InputObject $output -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "BytesSent" -Value $null
    Add-Member -InputObject $output -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "BytesRecived" -Value $null
    Add-Member -InputObject $output -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "ProcessingTime" -Value $null
    Add-Member -InputObject $output -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "ProtocolVersion" -Value $null
    Add-Member -InputObject $output -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Host" -Value $null
    Add-Member -InputObject $output -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "UserAgent" -Value $null
    Add-Member -InputObject $output -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Cookie" -Value $null
    Add-Member -InputObject $output -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Referer" -Value $null
}

process
{
    foreach($line in Get-Content -Path $Path -Encoding $Encoding)
    {
        if($line.StartsWith("#Fields: "))
        {
            $fieldNames = @($line.Substring("#Fields: ".Length).Split($Delimiter));
        }
        elseif(-not $line.StartsWith("#"))
        {
            $fieldValues = @($line.Split($Delimiter));
            
            for($i = 0; $i -lt $fieldValues.Length; $i++)
            {
                $name = $fieldNames[$i]
                $value = $fieldValues[$i]
                
                switch($name)
                {
                "date" { $output.DateTime = [DateTime]::Parse($value) }
                "time" { $output.DateTime += [TimeSpan]::Parse($value) }
                "c-ip" { $output.ClientHost = [System.Net.IPAddress]::Parse($value) }
                "cs-username" { $output.UserName = if($value -eq '-') { $null } else { $value } }
                "s-sitename" { $output.Service = $value }
                "s-computername" { $output.Machine = $value }
                "s-ip" { $output.ServerIp = [System.Net.IPAddress]::Parse($value) }
                "s-port" { $output.ServerPort = [int]$value }
                "cs-method" { $output.Method = $value }
                "cs-uri-stem" { $output.ScriptPath = [System.Web.HttpUtility]::UrlDecode($value) }
                "cs-uri-query" { $output.QueryString = if($value -eq '-') { $null } else { [System.Web.HttpUtility]::UrlDecode($value) } }
                "sc-status" { $output.ServiceStatus = [int]$value }
                "sc-substatus" { $output.ServiceSubStatus = [int]$value }
                "sc-win32-status" { $output.Win32Status = [BitConverter]::ToInt32([BitConverter]::GetBytes([UInt32]($value)), 0) }
                "sc-bytes" { $output.BytesSent = [UInt64]$value }
                "cs-bytes" { $output.BytesRecived = [UInt64]$value }
                "time-taken" { $output.ProcessingTime = [int]$value }
                "cs-version" { $output.ProtocolVersion = $value }
                "cs-host" { $output.Host = if($value -eq '-') { $null } else { $value } }
                "cs(User-Agent)" { $output.UserAgent = if($value -eq '-') { $null } else { $value } }
                "cs(Cookie)" { $output.Cookie = if($value -eq '-') { $null } else { $value } }
                "cs(Referer)" { $output.Referer = if($value -eq '-') { $null } else { [System.Web.HttpUtility]::UrlDecode($value) } }
                }
            }
            
            Write-Output $output
        }
    }
}
```

Source: https://web.archive.org/web/20170430094952/https://poshcode.org/2574

Answer (score 0):

ConvertFrom-Csv works pretty well. You need to strip out the comment lines and provide a list of headers.

```
$headers @("Date", "Time", ..., "TimeTaken")
Get-Content "u_ex130815.log" | select -Skip 4| ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter " " -Header $headers | ? timetaken -gt 999
```